# Implement asyncio async await

Tags: python, django-rest-framework, async-await, python-asyncio

below is my patch API to update fields in a model. I need to run the try except block which is patching permissions through external API's to run async with this patch api.

```
@staticmethod
def patch(request, pk):
    """
    Update specific content request fields
    Patch Tenant and Customer Permissions in License
    @param request:
    @param pk: content request id
    @return:
    """

    content_request = get_object_or_404(ContentRequest, pk=pk)
    serializer = content_request_serializers.ContentRequestPatchSerializer(
        content_request, data=request.data, context={"request": request}, partial=True
    )
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()

        try:
            if content_request.status == "purchased":
                logger.info("Patching Permissions in License for Tenant and Customer")
                response_1 = (
                    applisting_helper.FetchServiceLicenseInfo()
                    .send_request(params={"service_id": content_request.content_service_id})
                    .json()
                )
                module = response_1[0].get("module_name")
                submodule_id = response_1[0].get("submodule_id")
                response_2 = (
                    lic_helper.FetchSubmoduleData(submodule_id)
                    .send_request()
                    .json()
                    .get("sub_module_data")
                )
                submodule = response_2.get("sub_module_name")
                permissions = response_1[0].get("permissions")
                data = []
                for permission in permissions:
                    data.append(module + "." + submodule + "." + permission)
                tenant_id = content_request.tenant
                lic_helper.PatchTenantPermissions(tenant_id).send_request(
                    payload={"permissions": data}
                )
                logger.info("Successfully patched Tenant Permissions in License")
                response_3 = (
                    lic_helper.FetchTenantData(tenant_id)
                    .send_request()
                    .json()
                    .get("tenant_data")
                )
                customer_id = response_3.get("customer_id")
                lic_helper.PatchCustomerPermission(customer_id).send_request(
                    payload={"permissions": data}
                )
                logger.info("Successfully patched Customer Permissions in License")
            else:
                logger.warning("No new permissions patched")

        except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:
            logger.warning(
                "Failed to connect to the License host, skipping permission patching"
            )
            return
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
    return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```